# Scala Play: how to define a "Json writable class"

Tags: json, scala, playframework, playframework-2.5

I would like to write a function that transforms case classes to Json:

```
import play.api.libs.json._

def myJson(cc: Product): JsValue = {
  Json.toJson(cc)  // simplified
}
```

Each case class has an implicit `Writes[T]`, for example:

```
case class Test(a: Int)
object Test {
  implicit val jsonWrites: Writes[Test] = Json.writes[Test]
}
```

It is possible to write `Json.toJson(new Test(1))` individually, but the `myJson` function above does not compile because it never knows if `cc` has an implicit Writes defined.

[How can I write the function signature so that it takes only classes having a `Writes` implicit?]

Edit: How can I write the function input type so that it corresponds only to classes having a `Writes` implicit?

I tried this:

```
trait JsonWritableResult[T <: Product] {
  implicit val jsonWrites: Writes[T]
}

case class Test(a: Int)
object Test extends JsonWritableResult[Test] {
  implicit val jsonWrites: Writes[Test] = Json.writes[Test]
}

def myJson(cc: JsonWritableResult[_ <: Product]): JsValue = {
  Json.toJson(cc)
}
```

But it says **"No Json serializer found for type models.JsonWritableResult[_$2]"**.

Comment: Why do you want your custom myJson function for arbitrary case class? How will it be different from Json.toJson?

Comment: Simply because I have 120 such case classes and I don't want to write 120 controllers to return that many different Json results. A generic function would be best.

Comment: @Tyth Note that it may be dumb indeed but I haven't realized it yet )

Comment: You simply need to accept a `(implicit writes: Writes[T])` in your `myJson` method. What does it mean ? You are requiring the compiler to check whether the provided type has an instance of `Writes`

Comment: If I understand well, that is the signature that `Json.toJson` already has. What I really need is a trait/type that I can give to all results of a factory so that they are guaranteed to be valid arguments to `toJson`. Looks like the question was asked badly :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this seems to give you the behavior you want.

```
import play.api.libs.json.{JsValue, Json, Writes}

trait Product {}

case class Test(a: Int) extends Product
object Test {
  implicit val jsonWrites: Writes[Test] = Json.writes[Test]
}

def myJson[T <: Product](cc: T)(implicit writes: Writes[T]): JsValue = {
  Json.toJson(cc)  // simplified
}

import Test._

myJson(Test(3))
```

This is not tested in the general case, but in a Worksheet it seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of forcing the case class to have the implicit, it is more clever to force it to override a `toJson` method from a trait, using or not an implicit defined in the case class. Much simpler and it works. Then my factory can explicit this trait in its output type, and thus I can serialize whatever it outputs.

But since the other answer answered the question that I formulated wrong, I accept it ;)